# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED refused when opening React App on chrome using http://public_ip:port

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, frontend, ip, web-deployment

So if I try to open my react app using `http://localhost:port`, then it works. but if open the webpage using my actual public IP4 address like so `http://public_ip:port`, it gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

What is causing this and how do I fix it?
I believe that my linux mint firewall is in `inactive` state.

EDITED:

The app is hosted in the same machine as the chrome.

Comment: Are you accessing it from the machine which is host to the server or from another device?

Comment: Where are you hosting your application? Do you have a web server like nginx or apache? IF you are running on a web server, make sure that you are running the host on `0.0.0.0` and not on `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`.

Comment: It is the same machine. I am hosting it in the same machine that I am running the chrome. It is in development.

Comment: did you try whit another browser?

Comment: tried with firefox. same. unable to connect.